# Include in a public repository specific directories of another repo using git

Tags: git, github, repository

I have two repositories on GitHub - one public and one private. I would like to make publicly visible some of the code (in specific directories) in the private repo, ideally via the public repository.

Is this possible without having two copies of the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, its not possible to expose only certain directories of a git repository. You would have to host those directories separately. See a related question [here](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#How_do_I_clone_a_subdirectory.3F) (How do I clone a subdirectory?).

Comment: the link you refer to seems to be broken

Comment: That was a kernel.org link -- and it looks like kernel.org is not up even now. I tried looking for the same thing elsewhere but I can't the kernel.org git FAQ anywhere. As soon as I find something I will add another link.